# asyncio creates dozens of subprocesses and never closes them

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot that runs on both Windows and Linux. It's a pretty normal bot that displays messages, has commands etc. But I also added reading text files in background to send them as messages in the discord later.

Apparenty I messed something up with asyncio and on Linux some people have lots of empty subprocesses that just sit there and do nothing. Bot works okay for them though.

I asked this question in the Discord API server and was told that discord.py doesn't cause this so the issue is somewhere in my code, which is quite possible since I'm not a pro in Python and getting async stuff to work cross-platform was hard.

What causes my problem and how to solve it?

[image]

```
import os, sys, math, re, time, threading, asyncio, signal, json, discord, psutil
from pathlib import Path
from mcrcon import MCRcon
from discord.ext import commands

# ..Lots of code..

async def update():
    while runApp:
        try:
            # Collect data for bot to display
            await attemptReading()
            await asyncio.sleep(settings['update-interval'])
        except asyncio.CancelledError: # Never occurs for some reason
            break
    print("'update' task and event loop stopped")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
 

def ask_exit():
    print("Stop tasks..")
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
updateTask = loop.create_task(update())

# Run bot
print("Ctrl+C to stop the bot")
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(bot.start(settings['token']))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Shutting down..")
    loop.run_until_complete(bot.logout())
    botIsReady = False
    runApp = False
    print("Cancel tasks")
    # cancel all tasks
    try:
        for sig in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
            loop.add_signal_handler(sig, ask_exit)
    except NotImplementedError: # Windows
        pass
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    print("Shutted down")
    loop.close()
```

Comment: What's in the rest of the code? Is it possible that you use `subprocess` or `multiprocessing` somewhere? Or `ProcessPoolExecutor` maybe?

Comment: Please produce a [mcve].

Comment: user4815162342, No I don't use any of those. The rest of the code is a pretty usual stuff like reading files and sending messages via discord bot